# How to use assumption local strong convexity

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

**My problem:** We consider Newton's method for optimization problem under the following assumption:

- Lipschitz Hessian: $\left\|\nabla^2 f(x)-\nabla^2 f(y)\right\| \leq M\|x-y\|$
- Local strong convexity: There exists a local minimum $x^*$ with
  $$
  \nabla^2 f\left(x^*\right) \succeq \mu I, \quad \mu>0 .
  $$
- Locality: Starting point $x_0$ "close enough" to $x^*$
  We need to prove that: Suppose $x_0$ satisfies
  $$
  \left\|x_0-x^*\right\|<r:=\frac{2 \mu}{3 M} .
  $$
  Then, $\left\|x_k-x^*\right\|<r, \forall k$.
  **My attempt:**
  \begin{aligned}
  \mathbf{x}_{k+1}-\mathbf{x}^* & =\mathbf{x}_k-\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1} \nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)-\mathbf{x}^* \\
  & { = }  \mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{x}^*+\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\left(\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}^*\right)-\nabla f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right) \\
  & =\mathbf{x}_k-\mathbf{x}^*+\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1} \int_0^1\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k+t\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)\right]\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right) d t \\
  & =\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1} \int_0^1\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k+t\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)-\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right]\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right) d t
  \end{aligned}
  That implies
  \begin{aligned}
  \left\|\mathbf{x}_{k+1}-\mathbf{x}^*\right\| & \leq\left\|\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\right\|\left\|\int_0^1\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k+t\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)-\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right]\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right) d t\right\| \\
  & \leq\left\|\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\right\| \int_0^1\left\|\left[\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k+t\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)-\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right]\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right\| d t \\
  & \leq\left\|\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\right\| \int_0^1\left\|\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k+t\left(\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)-\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right\| \cdot\left\|\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right\| d t\\
  & \leq\left\|\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\right\| \dfrac{M^2}{2}\left\|\mathbf{x}^*-\mathbf{x}_k\right\| 
  \end{aligned}
  From here, I need to evaluate $\left\|\left(\nabla^2 f\left(\mathbf{x}_k\right)\right)^{-1}\right\|$ but I don't know how to do this. I think that I need to use the assumption of local strong convexity.

Comment: You need to show that e.g. $\nabla^2 f(x) \ge \mu/2 I_n$ for $x$ close to $x^*$.

Comment: Yes, I used to think about this idea. But  I don't know how to used. I intend to use the matrix norm in equality. Is it correct? @daw. Can you help me to do it clearly?

Comment: @daw sorry, i didn't tag you in the previous comment